# How should I use parse_mode='HTML' in telegram python bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a message in a channel with a bot, using Telegram API's `send_photo()` method. It takes a caption parameter (type `String`) but I can't format it through `parse_mode='HTML'` parameter...

If I use something like this:

```
send_photo(chat_id, photo, caption="<b>Some text</b>", parse_mode='HTML')
```

it sends the message but without any kind of formatting. Does anybody know why? Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you need to *import* `ParseMode` *from* `telegram` like this:

```
from telegram import ParseMode
```

Then, all you need is to specify `parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML`. Here's a working example:

```py
def jordan(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    with open('JordanPeterson.jpg', 'rb') as jordan_picture:
        caption = "<a href='https://twitter.com/jordanbpeterson'>Jordan B. Peterson</a>"
        bot.send_photo(
            chat_id, 
            photo=jordan_picture, 
            caption=caption,
            parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
        )
```

And we can see that it works:

[image: works]

Update: Actually, both `parse_mode='html'` (as suggested by [@slackmart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104879/6282576)) and `parse_mode='HTML'` that you used yourself work for me!

Another Update (as per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104009/how-should-i-use-parse-mode-html-in-telegram-python-bot/56104879#comment98864623_56104879)): You *can* use multiple tags. Here's an example of one, with `hyperlink`, `bold`, and `italic`:

[image: multiple tags]

Yet Another Update: Regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104009/how-should-i-use-parse-mode-html-in-telegram-python-bot/56104879#comment98874501_56104879):

> ...do I have any limitations on HTML tags? I can't use something like `<img>` or `<br>` to draw a line

Honestly,

[image: try and find out]

That's what I did!

Now you're trying to format the *caption* of an image, using `HTML`, meaning you're formatting a `text`, so obviously, you can't use "something like `<img>`." It has to be a "[text formatting tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp)" (plus `<a>`). And not even all of them! I believe you can only use these: `<a>`, `<b>`,  `<strong>`, `<i>` and `<em>`.

If you try to use a text-formatting tag like `<del>`, it will give you this error:

> Can't parse entities: **unsupported** start tag "del" at byte offset 148

Which is a shame! <del>I'd love to be able to do something like this in captions of images.</del><sub>or something like this!</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As per version 20, you need to use:

`from telegram.constants import ParseMode`

More about it in the official docs here: https://pythontelegramrobot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.parsemode.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It works for me! Here's the code I'm using:

```
>>> from telegram import Bot
>>> tkn = '88888:199939393'; chid = '-31828'
>>> bot = Bot(tkn)
>>> with open('ye.jpeg', 'rb') as fme:
...   bot.send_photo(chid, fme, caption='<b>Hallo</b>', parse_mode='html')
...
<telegram.message.Message object at 0x7f6301b44d10>
```

Of course, you must use your own telegram token and channel id. Also notice I'm using `parse_mode='html'  # lowercase`

Comment: huh, I always did it with `parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML`. Didn't think `parse_mode='html'` would work as well! +1 for that.

Comment: BTW, your answer suggests that the problem is with `HTML`, being uppercase. However, `html` works as well.

Comment: Thanks, but do I have a limitation on tags I can use? I mean, I can't use <a href=...> on caption, right? Or is there a way to use it the same?

Comment: @Federico check out my second update. Also, you *can* use `<a href=""></a>`! Did you even look at my answer?

Comment: @Amir sorry, I saw your update now...I see that I can use <a href> tags in captions but do I have any limitations on HTML tags? I can't use something like <img> or <br> to draw a line

Comment: @Federico I added another update to address your concern. Let's move the conversation under my own answer, as to not make unnecessary noise for [@slackmart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977593/slackmart). However, comments are not meant for extended conversations, if there's something that hasn't been answered, you should update your question to make it clear as what you wish to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<br>` use `\n`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my issue!